# uninterruptible sleep

Tags: linux

I have some process that is in uninterruptible sleep due to limited memory. After I kill other processes, there is enough memory available for it now. How do I change the status of the process from uninterruptible sleep to normal running? Or the OS will automatically make the change?  Or do I have to kill it and start it agian? 
Thanks and regards!

Comment: How do you know that it is memory that is what causes it to go into uninterruptible sleep?

Comment: I see the top for available memory and swap. I know how much the process will need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uninterruptible means uninterruptible. You can't kill it without a reboot and you can't force a status change. If the state that is causing this resolves itself or a timeout expires, the process should resume. You may have some other I/O that is blocked and causing this or it may be a bug.

[More info](http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.misc/2006-01/msg00994.html)