# Force KILL State -D Process/PID in Linux

Tags: linux, kill

Can anyone show me how to Force KILL State -D Process/PID in Linux? I am looking everywhere and no answer found yet.

```
PID   USER     PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13585 ggreik  16   0  8600 5508 1648  D  0.0  0.0   0:00.17  fluxbox
```

Really appreciate if expert out there could give me answer to this, I know reboot of a server could resolve the issue but that would be my last resort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [uninterruptible sleep](http://serverfault.com/questions/99659/uninterruptible-sleep)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a process is in an "uninterruptible sleep" it's either waiting on I/O or it has encountered a bug.  As with its name, it is indeed uninterruptible.  You can wait for the resource to free up or help the resource free up, which will help the process state to change.  Hopefully, it will be a state that will allow you to terminate the process.

It could also be potentially waiting on a resource from a parent process.  With GNU ps, you can run using the `f` option to enable thread view.

fluxbox is a window manager, so it likely has X as a parent process.  Try killing X before fluxbox.

Otherwise, the only realistic option is to reboot.